# does exist convenience manner to import project without .project exist in eclispe

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse mars I checked out a svn project without .project exist, so when I import this project , it hints

```
No projects are found to import
```

So does exist convenience manner to import project like this ?

Comment: no, now I got those files (.classpath .project) from history version e.g. svn copy https://repos/project/modules/module.js@3502 modules/module.js

Answer (score 0):

Typically I do not like people having Eclipse `.settings/`, `.project` and `.classpath` is version control system. Especially, when I'm using maven and there is `mvn eclipse:eclipse` command...

Answer (score 0):

Could just use eclipse svn plugin, e.g subclipse

now I have a svn repository url and does not exist .classpath .project .settings in it

1. checkout project by subclipse and check the first option

[image]

2. create a local web project use code in repository
   [image]
3. even if repository does not have .classpath .project .settings still could create a local web project

[image]